# What can we conclude about the function $f$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, self-learning

> Let $f$ be a scalar field, $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$. Suppose there is an $n$-ball $B(a;r)$ centered at $a$ with radius $r$ and a fixed vector $y\in\mathbb R^n$ such that $f'(x;y)=0$ for every $x\in B(a;r)$. What can you conclude about $f$?

This problem is from Apostol Calculus Volume 2. I have just begun the subject. However, I did try to work out as follows:

> It is evident, from Mean Value Theorem, that for any $x\in B(a;r)$, we have $f(x+y)-f(x)=f'(x+\theta y;y)=0$, supposing that $x+y\in B(a;r)$ and hence $x+\theta y\in B(a;r)$ if $0<\theta<1$. (Here's my first question: can we assume that just because $x\in B(a;r)$ that $x+y\in B(a;r)$ also?)
>
> Anyway this gives that $f(x+y)=f(x)$ for each $x\in B(a;r)$.

I am not sure what I am supposed to conclude from here. I tried to interpret it by drawing an open ball around $a$ and taking a few points $x_1,x_2,x_3$ inside the ball, I tried to plot $x_i+y$ (in parallel straight lines), $i=1,2,3$ but I couldn't understand if this is anything significant.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symmetry $f(x+ty)=f(x)$ (whenever $x,x+ty\in B(a;r)$) is in fact equivalent with $f'(x;y)=0$ in $B(a;r)$.
You can observe this by differentiating in the direction of $y$; you need not consider any other derivatives.

If you write $\mathbb R^n=\mathbb R\oplus y^\perp$ (directions parallel and orthogonal to $y$), the function $f$ only depends on the variable in $y^\perp$ (which is $n-1$ dimensional).
If $y=(1,0,\dots,0)$, the conclusion is clearer.
Then $f$ only depends on $x_2,\dots,x_n$, not on $x_1$.

It does not follow from $x\in B(a;r)$ that also $x+y\in B(a;r)$.
But since the ball is open, it does follow that for real numbers $t$ close enough to zero, $x+ty\in B(a;r)$.
You can use the mean value theorem (or the fundamental theorem of calculus along a line) on shorter line segments just as well.

Comment: My apologies: I intially had somehow over-read that the ball $B(a;r)$ is open, but in the question it is just mentioned that $B(a;r)$ is a ball. In any case, what I realize is that you are trying to say that $f$ depends only on the components of the input vector that are in $y^{\perp}$. Am I correct?

Comment: @LandonCarter, typically "a ball" means automatically "an open ball", but it depends on the book. I don't remember Apostol's conventions. The claim about the function $f$ is true in a closed ball as well, though. Yes, $f$ only depends on directions normal to $y$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Seizing this opportunity, I would like to ask you, have I taken the right decision to start Multivariable Calculus with Apostol Vol. 2? I have a one-year undergraduate knowledge in all aspects of linear Real Analysis and Linear Algebra.

Comment: @LandonCarter, I don't know what would be the best possible choice, but I'm confident that yours is a good one. If you ever want a different approach to the topic later on, it will be much faster for you to read a new book from a new angle, so time is not wasted with a suboptimal book.